# What is the difference between findById() and existsById() in Spring Data 2.0?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data

Spring Data 2.0 JpaRepository: difference between `findById()` and `existsById()`

- Which scenario do we use `findById()` and `existsById()` methods?

Comment: You can find more information here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.html

Comment: This is Spring Data JPA which is NOT the same as JPA API. Kindly fix the tags on this to remove the `jpa` tag

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.html):

existsById(ID id) - returns ***boolean***

> Returns whether an entity with the given id exists.

findById(ID id) - returns ***Optional (object)***

> Retrieves an entity by its id.

Simple as that - `findById()` returns object, which you are searching for, `existsById()` returns true/false whether or not entity exists in repository.

Comment: Hi, I would like to ask which one is better based on performance perspective?

Answer (score 5):

Performance test on findBy and existsBy using simple entity (id,name)

[image]

Comment: Did adding an extra 100,000 records really double the time of `findBy`?

Comment: That was my observation with my development environment. I appreciate if anyone else try it and share the results.

Answer (score 1):

The findById(...) and getOne(...) is much faster than the existsById(...), it is not clear then why the existsById(...) was invented

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31426531)

Answer (score 1):

I have run couple of tests with both of them and it seems to me performance changes times to times but in general existById seems to be a little bit faster for me. Taking into account findById needs to create java object to return existById seems to be better approach when we check existence.

Answer (score 1):

for spring data redis implementation, it looks like `existsById` is just calling `findById`

```
public boolean existsById(ID id) {
    return this.findById(id).isPresent();
}
```

Comment: I suppose this would only work on composite ids?